# SQL Group By equivalent

Tags: sql, oracle

Pretend I have a `cupcake_rating` table:

```
id     |     cupcake      |    delicious_rating
--------------------------------------------
1      |     Strawberry   |    Super Delicious
2      |     Strawberry   |    Mouth Heaven
3      |     Blueberry    |    Godly
4      |     Blueberry    |    Super Delicious
```

I want to find all the cupcakes that have a 'Super Delicious' AND 'Mouth Heaven' rating. I feel like this is easily achievable using a `group by` clause and maybe a `having`.

I was thinking:

```
select distinct(cupcake) 
  from cupcake_rating 
 group by cupcake 
having delicious_rating in ('Super Delicious', 'Mouth Heaven')
```

I know I can't have two separate AND statements. I was able to achieve my goal using:

```
select distinct(cupcake) 
  from cupcake_rating 
 where cupcake in ( select cupcake 
                      from cupcake_rating 
                     where delicious_rating = 'Super Delicious' ) 
   and cupcake in ( select cupcake 
                      from cupcake_rating 
                     where delicious_rating = 'Mouth Heaven' )
```

This will not be satisfactory because once I add a third type of rating I am looking for, the query will take hours (there are a lot of cupcake ratings).

Comment: `select distinct cupcake from table where delicious_rating in(select delicious_ratings_here from table)`

Comment: this will return Strawberry and Blueberry, but really I only want Strawberry

Comment: You may be surprised if you run tests with the various versions. My bet would be on the `IN`, `EXISTS` and `JOIN` versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're correct, you can use a HAVING clause; there's no need to use a self-join either.

You want only a cupcake with two ratings, so restrict to those two ratings and then check that the DISTINCT number of ratings is equal to two:

```
select cupcake
  from cupcake_rating
 where delicious_rating in ('Super Delicious', 'Mouth Heaven')
 group by cupcake
having count(distinct delicious_rating) = 2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/55152/1)

This is far more easily extensible as you don't need to do a new self-join for every delicious rating, you just have to check that you have the number you want.

Comment: Yes @Alex :-). I was almost stopped writing this when I saw you'd posted, then (with a small amount of shock) continued :-)

Comment: If the self-join managed it in 9.121s I'd be interested to know how this compares in your environment @MikeB?

Comment: This query only works if you can have at most one rating type per cupcake.  For example, this query will give you a false positive if you  have a Rasberry cupcake that was rated "Super Delicious" twice and "Mouth Heaven" zero times.

Comment: I'm counting the distinct delicious ratings @steaks, so I don't see how that's possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can join all "Super Delicious" ratings to "Mouth Heaven" ratings on `cupcake`.  This way you find all cupcakes that had both "Super Delicious" and "Mouth Heaven" ratings.

```
SELECT DISTINCT cr.cupcake
FROM cupcake_rating cr
JOIN cupcake_rating cr2
    ON cr.cupcake = cr2.cupcake
WHERE cr.delicious_rating = 'Super Delicious'
    AND cr2.delicious_rating = 'Mouth Heaven'
```

Comment: Nice! Yours got me the same 24 rows in 9.121 seconds compared to the 1008.253 mine did

Comment: So when are you sharing those cupcakes?

Answer (score 1):

`I want to find all the cupcakes that have a 'Super Delicious' AND 'Mouth Heaven' rating`

I understand the requirement above to mean the cupcake must have achieved each of those ratings, not merely one or the other.  In other words, if *everyone* rated the cupcake as Mouth Heaven, it would not qualify.

```
          select distinct cupcake from cupcake_ratings A where rating = 'super'
          inner join
          (
           select distinct cupcake from cupcake_ratings where rating = 'heaven'
          ) x
          on A.cupcake = x.cupcake
```

gets you the list of cupcakes with both ratings.

P.S. You could probably optimize this with EXISTS if you had a CUPCAKES table:

```
         select cupcake from cupcakes
         where exists
         (
            select cupcake from ratings where rating = 'super'
            and ratings.cupcake = cupcakes.cupcake
         )

         and exists
         (
            select cupcake from ratings where rating = 'heaven'
            and ratings.cupcake = cupcakes.cupcake
         )
```